# What is the difference between: "He had to arrive..." "He had to have arrived..."

Tags: modal-verbs

- He **had to arrive** before we began yesterday.
- He **had to have arrived** before we began yesterday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple. The first sentence indicates obligation in the past,
and the second sentence indicates deduction in the past, but the second usage is not very common.

Comment: Both sentences take about the past, and that has raised ambiguity in my understanding. Thanks, now both are clear: (1) obligation, (2) deduction

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of the difference between [perfect tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar)) and [pluperfect tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluperfect)? : )

You can think of it this way: both of these sentences take the perspective of someone present at that moment in the past. In the first sentence, you're talking about him arriving at that moment; in the second sentence, you're talking about him already *having* arrived at that moment.

Does that make sense?