# Had to have been

Tags: perfect-infinitive

I watch a very popular video game streamer, he is American and I have just heard him say "It had to have been". After that I immediately rushed to https://www.englishpage.com/modals/haveto.html, but didn't find this construction. I have seen this [What is the difference between: "He had to arrive..." "He had to have arrived..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/96458/what-is-the-difference-between-he-had-to-arrive-he-had-to-have-arrived), but I don't think that the streamer was deducing, it was certainty. You can hear the speech by following https://www.twitch.tv/videos/167278867?t=02h29m45s

Can somebody explain the difference between:

> has to have been

and

> had to have been

Comment: *He didn't accept the election result. He said it **had to have been** rigged.* Using past perfect is quite natural in such contexts (it's equivalent to *It **must have been** rigged*), because he's talking about something (the "rigging") that happened ***before*** his reaction to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't visit the website, but that construction (**had to have been**) is used when someone is thinking back, placing himself at a time in the past, wondering about a particular thing or event, and answering the implicit question, What circumstance would explain that particular past situation? What was happening *before* it happened, which would explain it?

Yesterday, our dog was barking. Why?
--It had to have been because the neighbor's cat was in our garden.

"has|had to BE" is a periphrasis for "must".

-- It must have been because the neighbor's cat was in our garden.

The dog was barking *a moment ago*. I wonder why?
--It has to have been the neighbor's cat. He was barking yesterday for that reason.

Why *is* the dog barking now?
--It *has* to be that damn cat again.

Comment: In practice I'm not sure it really makes any *semantic* difference to say *It must **be** because the neighbor's cat **was** in our garden* in your example. But in, say, *What time did you get home last night? It must **have been** after midnight!* you have no choice but to "backshift".

Comment: I thought that "must" was less strong in certainty than "has to". I was wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: there's a term in mechanical engineering which can be applied to language: **slop**. It might be paraphrased as "wiggle room". We often content ourselves with the mere gist of an idea, and so we can get by with quite a lot of 'slop' without the communication apparatus falling apart. But that isn't to say there isn't a nuanced difference between "it has to be the  neighbor's cat" and  "it has to have been the neighbor's cat" and "it had to have been the neighbor's cat" when offered as explanation for barking that took place last week.

Comment: Personally, I suspect any "nuanced difference" is more an "artefact" of language rather than a genuine *semantic* distinction in most contexts. But it would be interesting to see if there's an example where backshifting or not makes a clear-cut (and *significant*) difference.

Comment: If I offer as explanation for last week's barking the statement "It has to be the neighbor's cat"  or "It has to have been the neighbor's cat", one might infer that I believe that cat to be a nuisance and to have been a nuisance for some time now.  I'm coloring the explanation for the past event with a tinge of  my present outlook. Further, if I know the cat got run over by a car yesterday, I wouldn't say  "it has to be the neighbor's cat" though I might say "It has to have been the neighbor's cat".

Comment: The present and present perfect suggest that I'm using my experience up until this very moment, past experience and recent experience, to make the surmise about the past. Whereas if I cast the explanation in the past perfect, there is no cause for the listener to infer anything other than that my past experience is being drawn upon for the surmise.